# PCL Region Growing with LAB Color Space?

Tags: rgb, image-segmentation, point-cloud-library, region, lab-color-space

Anyone ever implemented or see a PCL Region Growing Color-Based in LAB?

I'm using the RGB based algorithm. I'm looking for a implementation in LAB but I cant found it.

This post http://www.pcl-developers.org/RGB-to-CIEL-color-space-color-based-segmentation-td5709511.html show how to convert RGB to LAB in PCL, but not implement a Region Growing.

Thank you.

Comment: What is your goal? Are you aiming to achieve the same result RGB segmentation would have?

Comment: Hello! I need to compare the result of segmentation between both color spaces. I whold loke to know how space color is better for my problem using region growing.

Answer (score 1):

Something to try would be to convert the LAB type cloud to RGB, but copy the channels over directly. So L->R, A->G, B->B. Once you have this cloud you could run it through the RGB region growing and see what kind of results it spits out. Not sure if this would be interesting to you.

Comment: In fact I already have the clouds in RGB. I need to convert them to LAB and then use an implementation of the Region Growing algorithm for LAB. I imagine that the calculation of the difference between colors is not the same as RGB.